# Are Canadian visitor visa wait times very high right now?

Tags: visas, canada

Has anyone have a recent experience of applying for a Canadian visitor visa?

I recently applied for a visitor visa last September for a trip this June. I know it feels like I applied way too early, but the official website has shown an approximate waiting/processing time to be 132 days.

This means that even if I applied last September, it is possible that results of my application will come out on February yet.

Has anyone experienced this long visa waiting time?

Waiting time used to be 1 month only in my country. Now I am a bit worried it might not be even ready by April.

Comment: You’re lucky Canada even allows you to apply so far in advance. For example, for a Schengen visitor visa the limit is 6 months before intended travel date (used to be 3), for the UK it’s 3 months.

Comment: I am slightly confused by your phrasing. You applied in September 2022, for a trip in June 2023? Why does waiting until February 2023 matter?

Comment: It might also help to include your country of nationality / where you are applying from?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- perhaps cgo is worried about the possibility that the visa will be approved so late that it will be impossible to find an affordable flight.

Comment: @phoog That is a plausible reason, which is why I asked cgo.

Answer (score 11):

The IRCC is [working on it](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/2022/08/tackling-immigration-backlogs-to-help-canadian-businesses-grow.html). While the IRCC does not publish such things, I readily presume they have internal priorities where new hires go and I suspect visitor visas are pretty far down on that list. Here are a few pressing issues the IRCC needs to tackle:

- Providing Canadians with passports. It's been [real bad](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/trudeau-passport-delays-unacceptable-1.6497417) just a few months ago and it's only slowly getting better.
- Processing refugees, especially with the war in Ukraine. Canada has a huge Ukrainian minority so it's much more a target than you'd think. There were about 200 000 pending Ukrainian refugee applications this summer -- compare this to the 400 000 permanent residents we welcomed in 2021.
- Processing work and immigration permits to ease labor shortages. We do not have enough doctors right now, this is a serious crisis with various levels / departments of the government working on solving it. Admitting more from abroad posthaste is one obvious angle.

A little patience please. The government is trying its best but there are a lot of fires.

Comment: More of a comment... but the "doctor shortage" in Canada has been a grotesque charade for decades. Most of them will end up driving taxis or barely getting by with odd jobs.

Comment: *"200 000 pending Ukrainian refugee applications"* oh you sweet summer child. Writing it from Poland. [Since February 24, 2022 **more than 6.9 million refugees** from Ukraine have crossed the **Polish** border.](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1293564/ukrainian-refugees-in-poland/) One would believe Canada can deal with mere 200 thousands.

Comment: We == Canadians. I edited the answer. Sigh. Silly me for trying to put a little personal touch in my answer :/ And there are not 6.9M refugees in Poland, https://www.polskieradio.pl/395/7784/Artykul/3050600,Poland-welcomes-69-million-refugees-from-Ukraine-officials more than 5.13 million people have left Poland for Ukraine since February 24, the agency also reported. -- the remaining 1.77M is still a staggering amount but it's not clear whether they all asked for asylum or are temporary.

Comment: There are other places for Ukrainians to go to from Poland than just Ukraine.  Some of the 1.77 million must have gone on to other places rather than remaining in Poland.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can trust any information from IRCC at this time. Estimated processing times might be completely off.

I personally applied for a transit visa as a Colombian citizen living in South Korea, and the estimated processing time was 25 days. I got my biometrics, and there was no response for 3 months. I know of numerous cases (seriously, numerous) of people travelling to South Korea through Canada who lost their tickets for the same reason.

In my case, I got a refusal letter saying that my "temporary resident visa" was rejected... but I was actually applying for a transit visa. The situation might be much worse with visitor visas, and the internets is plagued with such complaints.

Comment: Temporary resident visas include all visas other than permanent resident (immigration) visas in Canada so it was not incorrect.. But yes, the wait time is ridiculously long. My friend's temporary visa application has been in process for almost six months now without response (and they had visited and studied in Canada before!).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But yes, maybe it's better to visit Greenland at the moment?

Comment: It does seem like applying for pretty much *any* visitor visa to any of the most popular destinations is not a great idea right now unless there’s a compelling need for the trip and/or the applicant can be flexible on the date of travel without jeopardising the application decision. Can’t help thinking that allowing applications many months in advance might be contributing to the backlog, it might even be better to pause visit applications (except transit) for a few months to allow some time to work through the backlog

Comment: Why would they want to prioritise transit applications? Someone who is merely in transit almost certainly brings less value to the country than someone who is actually visiting.

Comment: @PeterGreen especially since transit visas are free of charge.

Comment: I read the post in the answer by @chx. The number of applications must be crazy if they admit more than 400.000 residents per year.